# Dual-booting Linux, cannot view images, some text or buttons

Tags: install, unix, dual-boot, efi

I was trying to boot 4 linux OSes (using rEFInd): Kali, Ubuntu, Mint and Elementary on my 2015 MBP. Both Kali and Ubuntu would not boot at all and Linux Mint and Elementary would boot however some text, graphics and images would not show (tested on a PC and virtual box and it worked).

How would I fix this issue? Do I need drivers or something else? I cannot see the text to connect to the network and the Applications will not show correctly.

Comment: Unless you really need direct access to the physical Apple hardware, IMO, Linux runs much better in a virtual machine on a Mac then a physical install on a Mac. I use VMware Fusion as it's more refined then VirtualBox.  I'm mentioning this because I too tried running Linux Mint 17.1 on an early 2013 MBPr and had issues that I just didn't feel like trying to fix when it runs just fine in a VM.

Comment: I want it so I can view my Raspberry Pi's SD card and use the `cfdisk`,`fdisk` and `parted` on it too. I may also use the commands to make my rEFInd partition smaller too. I would also like to do it `just because I can`. :) I did think about VMing it though.

Comment: Was able to EFI boot Ubuntu on my 2007 iMac for the first time yesterday.  Considering this Mac does not have a UEFI, I consider this quite an achievement.  I was also able to configure rEFInd to boot Ubuntu via grub. Runs considerable faster then when I tested using VirtualBox.

Comment: Elementary says it is Mac comparable. Elementary also has EFI support. Do you know how to help me.

Comment: If you want another user to see your comment, then you have to include a @ character followed by a username. For example: @DavidAnderson.

Comment: Are you trying to get any linux to run on your Mac? Or, are you trying to get all 4 to run? Also, are you trying to install on a internal or external disk?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Any Linux. Rather elementary since it looks like OS X but still has the Linux commands. The 4 were ones I tried. Don't mind what one though.

Comment: I would try elementary, but it looks like it cost money. Besides, you already said you had problems with it. Do you have any preference over a free linux version. I installed Fedora a few months ago on a 2011 iMac. I did not have  any problems installing or booting. Well, one problem. You can not have hybrid GPT/MBR partitioning during installation. I believe that required 3 partitions to install. One was LVM with additional internal partitions.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Elementary is free. Just click custom amount and enter $0.

Comment: @user3439894 very useful insight re VM vs. physical install - thank you for sharing!